# Play Framework 2.0 Mailer Plugin

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have been using the amazing email plugin that was created for Play Frameworks 2.0. However, I have been struggling with attachments. I have a need to send excel docs as an attachment using this plugin. Has anyone had any experience with this? Is there maybe something I am missing? Could there be another way to send attachments in play? Any info would be greatly appreciated!

The plugin mentioned above can be found at https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer.

I have also asked this question on their issue tracker without any response.

Thanks guys,

Glen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i understand the mailer plugin api there is no function providing adding attachments. just for text and html.

have a look at http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html

Comment: thank you for your input. I will give this a try. If I had some rep points I would give you a plus one :D. thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it has been implemented in the lastest versions (it works for Play 2.2.x, I'm not sure it works with Play 2.0.x) : https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer

```
email.addAttachment("attachment.pdf", new File("/some/path/attachment.pdf"));
```

You just have to change your dependency in build.sbt : 
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0"

And change your play.plugins : 
    1500:play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin